# Flex transition. Fill the space in a smooth way

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

How to make flex transition smooth. In my example, when I click .center it jumps in an abrupt way. It is even more noticeable when the user clicks on document, .right fadeOut and .center jumps to fill all the space. Can I make those movement of .center more smooth? (similar to fadeIn and fadeOut of .right)

I do not know if this can be done with flex transition? I tried and makes no difference: transition: all 4s;

```js
$(".center").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
    $(".right").fadeIn(400);
}); 
 
 // click outside
$(document).click(function() {
    $(".right").fadeOut(400);
});
```

```css
#wrap {
 position: relative;
 margin: 20px auto;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: red;
}
 
.row {
 position: relative;
 height: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 
 display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 background-color: lightgray;
}
 
.center {
 min-height: 30px; line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: blue;
 flex-grow: 1;
}
 
.right {
 width: 50px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 10px;
 background-color: grey;
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div class="right">right</div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, that is not easily possible, at least not using this approach. fadeIn/fadeOut manipulate the opacity of the element, and toggle between display block/none - and the latter is instant, not transitionable. You would have to go with a different solution altogether, one that has both columns displayed to begin with, one with an initial effective width of 0, and then animate the width for both at the same time … or something similar to that.

Comment: For the first part of what 04FS describes, you can try with jQuery's `toggle`. Citing [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), "When a duration, a plain object, or a single "complete" function is provided, .toggle() becomes an animation method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```js
$(".center").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".right").fadeIn(400).css({
    'width': '50px',
    'margin-left': '10px'
  });
});

// click outside
$(document).click(function() {
  $(".right").fadeOut(400).css({
    'width': '0',
    'margin-left': '0'
  });
});
```

```css
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.center {
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.right {
  width: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center">center</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center">center</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem you have is that `display` cannot be transitioned and you need to have the initial state of the `right` element with a width of 0 and a margin of 0. You can set those properties in the jQuery though.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using opacity for right and transition with flex basis

1. On clicking center, set opacity 1 for right and reduced flex basis for center
2. On clicking right, set opacity 0 for right and 100% flex basis for center

```js
$(".center").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
    $(".right").css('opacity', '1');
    $(".right").css('flex', '0 0 50px');
    $('.center').css('flex', '0 0 calc(100% - 60px)');
}); 
 
 // click outside
$(document).click(function() {
    $(".right").css('opacity', '0');
    $(".right").css('flex', '0 0 0px)');
    $('.center').css('flex', '0 0 100%');
});
```

```css
#wrap {
 position: relative;
 margin: 20px auto;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: red;
}
 
.row {
 position: relative;
 height: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 10px; 
 display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 background-color: lightgray;
}
 
.center {
  line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: blue;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
 transition: all 1s;
}
 
.right {
 width: 50px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 10px;
 background-color: grey;
  flex: 0 0 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div class="right">right</div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like very much your solution. Nice fluid movements. Thank you so much. I have learn new things. I think I have to accept @disinfor answer just because it came first a few minutes before

Answer (score 0):

You can add transition in CSS via addClass, removeClass inside jquery code

[Codepen link for the code](https://codepen.io/soniaj204/pen/YoNZxa)

```
$(".center").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    $(".right").addClass('show');
}); 

    // click outside
$(document).click(function() {
    $(".right").removeClass('show');
});

.right {
    width: 50px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: grey;
    opacity: 0;
  visibility: none;
  transition: all 0.5s;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.right.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: If I understand, in your solution .center does not move, it does not flex. You make .right visible or not visible. It seems an interesting solution but it is different from what I was asking